# How to extract data from API call

Tags: reactjs, api, rest

[Geo ipify API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmoNe.png)

I have attached a screenshot for API result from the browser.

I am using this ReactJS function to fetch API

```
async function getIp() {
    const response = await fetch(`https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=${APP_KEY}&ipAddress=8.8.8.8`);
    const data = response.json();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.ip);    
  }
```

When I console.log(data.ip) its showing result undefined. Need help here!. How can I extract data from this API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to await json() because it also an async operation:

```
async function getIp() {
    const response = await fetch(`https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=${APP_KEY}&ipAddress=8.8.8.8`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.ip);    
}
```

Hopefully that helps!